# Splitting a CNN model to run in two devices

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

In a part of my research work, I am in need to split a deep Learning model(CNN) into two in order to run the model in two different devices in a distributed way. Here, I split a CNN model into two, A and B where the output of A will be the input for B. If anyone has an idea, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What model are you splitting?
In PyTorch it is possible to do so. Check the children function of a model in pytorch and reconstruct the layers for two sub models.

Comment: please don't answer a question with another question lol - add these questions to the comments so that op edits their post